# Form a Committee Of 10 Senators

Tags: combinatorics

The problem I'm working on reads: "How many different committees of 10 Senators can be formed if the two Senators from the same state, (50 States in All) are considered identical?"

This is the answer I got but I'm almost sure it's wrong:

$e_{1-50}=(1+x+x^2)$

$g(x)=(1+x+x^2)^{50}$

$(1+x+x^2)^{50}=\frac{(1-x^3)^{50}}{(1-x)^{50}}$
$=(1-x^3)^{50}*\frac{1}{(1-x)^{50}}$

$(1-x^3)^{50}=(1+(-1)(x^3 ))^{50}$
$=(1-C(50,1) x^3+C(50,2) x^6-C(50,3) x^9+⋯)$

$\frac{1}{(1-x)^{50}} =(1+C(50,1)x+C(51,2) x^2+⋯+C(59,10) x^{10}+⋯)$

$g(x)=(1-C(50,1) x^3+C(50,2) x^6-C(50,3) x^9+⋯)
   *(1+C(50,1)x+C(51,2) x^2+⋯+C(59,10) x^{10}+⋯)$

$a_{r}=C(59,10)-C(50,1)*C(56,7)+C(50,2)*C(53,4)-C(50,3)*C(50,1)=51,590,216,930$

I'm wondering where I went wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The way the question is phrased makes me think that there's still a pool of 100 senators, but a combination that contains 9 senators `California 1` is the same as a combination with the same 9 senators and `California 2` (as opposed to making combinations of 50 senators from different states). This would allow for combinations such as `CA1, CA2, OH1, OH2, DE1, DE2, MI1, MI2, AK1, AK2`

Answer (score 3):

We can count this by considering the number of states $i$ that contribute two senators:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{5}\binom{50}{i}\binom{50-i}{10-2i}=51590216930.
$$

Comment: So my answer was right?

Comment: It seems so. Although your math seems hard to read. Why not use the Tex mode to make it more readable (enclose in $, use \binom instead of C)?

Comment: I fixed it, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Your answer, and your method, are correct (not an approximation).

Answer (score 2):

i *think* i might have a solution.  you have at least $5$ states and at most $10$ with the $2$ senators in each state considered identical.  if it is $5$ states there are none left to choose otherwise there are $2,4,6,8,10$ states selected that have $1$ senator chosen.

${5\choose 0}{50\choose 5}+{6\choose 2}{50\choose 6}+{7\choose 4}{50\choose 7}+{8\choose 6}{50\choose 8}+{9\choose 8}{50\choose 9}+{10\choose 10}{50\choose 10}$

Comment: This seems to get the same answer as I came up with. I am supposed to be using generating functions.

Answer (score -1):

I wonder at the interpretation of the question.

If there were 50 pairs of counters of different colors, I can understand,
but how can you have a committee with identical **people** ?

I would think the answer is simply $\dbinom{50}{10}$

**Remarks**

Since you were asked to use a G.F. your interpretation and that of others must be right, but I am mystified why the questioner had to insert  "the two Senators from the same state, (50 States in All) are considered identical"

Comment: That doesn't allow for you to have two senators from the same state in the committee.

Comment: That's exactly the point. "...two Senators from the same state, (50 States in All) are considered identical." How can you have a committee with identical *people* ?